# Getting Error when scrolling the tableviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios

UITableViewController crashes with a exc bad accesses error. This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *cellText ;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        cellText = @"Mail1";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        cellText = @"Mail2";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cellText = @"Mail3";
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        cellText = @"Mail4";
    }
    else
    {
        cellText = @"Mail5";
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    return cell;
}
```

this is the log message xcode gave

> XXXXProject[1366:f803] *** -[XXXXViewController
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated
>   instance 0x6a793f0

Comment: On which line application crashes?

Comment: XXXXProject[1366:f803] *** -[XXXXViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a793f0  this is the log message xcode gave @janusfidel

Comment: It crashes in main.m file at these lines  @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: I think there are two possibilities for the crash 1.Problem with NSString or cell.DO one thing cell.textLabel.text = @"Static".Write this line before return cell statement.Then tell me whether you are getting the crash or not?

Comment: The error is not inside the method you posted but outside of it. Post more code...

Comment: @ohmprakash how do you create your tableview? possible reason is your tableview is already released.

Comment: It give me the same error when i scroll the table view. @Tendulkar

Comment: I'd bet the view controller is already released...

Comment: I use ARC for memory management @janusfidel

Comment: after the cellForRowAtIndex method called it calls dealloc method is there any problem in that and how can i fix that?

Comment: what are you doing in dealloc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to initialize cell. Maybe storyboard initializes cell.

[image: ss]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *cellText;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        cellText = @"Mail1";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        cellText = @"Mail2";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cellText = @"Mail3";
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        cellText = @"Mail4";
    }
    else
    {
        cellText = @"Mail5";
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    return cell;
}
```

You can download this sample project from GitHub, and just run it.

https://github.com/weed/p120817_TableTest

Comment: This is the Error i got
XXXXProject[1906:f803] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-08-17 15:23:02.965 NewProject[1906:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from

Comment: @weed this is not the solution. OP *has to* initialize the cell - he did what you wrote in this answer and he got the corresponding error.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same question was just posted on StackOverflow some hours before. (There not a table view called its delegate, but an UIButton its action). The problem probably is that you don't have a strong reference to your table view controller thus it's being deallocated immediately after creation. [See my answer to the previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000730/ios-memory-management-error-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance/12000767#12000767)

Comment: plz explain the details @H2CO3